# Two Topics with Same Callback

Tags: sensor-msgs, message-filters, image-transport, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am subscribing to two different topics (each with different md5sums) using a single callback. I am using the `message_filters`  class to achieve this. In my broadcaster, I am publishing a `point cloud` and an opencv `image`. I want to subscribe in a separate code. My callback signature looks like so:

```
 void callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& ensensoImage, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& ensensoCloud)
{
   cv::Mat ir; 
   PointCloudT cloud;
   getImage(ensensoImage, ir);
   getCloud(ensensoCloud, cloud);
   ROS_INFO_STREAM("cloud: " << cloud);

   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
   this->ir = ir;
   this->cloud = cloud;
   updateImage = true;
   updateCloud = true;
```

}

When I run my code, however, I get an `std::terminate` as follows:

```
user@user:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun ensenso ensenso_viewer 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::ConflictingSubscriptionException'
  what():  Tried to subscribe to a topic with the same name but different md5sum as a topic that was already subscribed [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181 vs. sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is it not possible to have a callback with different classes of a namespace or am I missing something?

For reference, the whole code is [here](https://github.com/lakehanne/ensenso/blob/devel/src/ensenso_viewer.cxx).

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251964/two-topics-with-same-callback/) by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2017-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-01-14**:
Why do you even need to do this in 1 callback function? Why don't just use 2 callback functions, store the data and create another function using the data? I've never encountered this approach and according to the error you've got it's not maybe even supported.

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-01-14**:
Did you read that I was using message_filters? The parameters are templated and the user should be free to put their classes within the policies as they might deem fit. I want to receive two different topics in a particular time. An ordinary callback would not fit my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you're trying to do seems reasonable.

The error you have happens when you create two subscribers on the same topic name, with different message types and checksums.

From you description, it sounds like your data is on two separate topics, so I suspect there's a typo or mis-configuration in your code somewhere.

And indeed, [here](https://github.com/lakehanne/ensenso/blob/ead0408f9b13d1f6d8eb56ef289b42105056551d/src/ensenso_viewer.cxx#L74-L75) is looks like you create two topic names, but then use the same topic name when subscribing to both topics:

```
spinner(4), subNameCloud(basetopic + "/cloud"), subNameIr(basetopic + "/ir_image"), 
subImageIr(nh, subNameIr, 1), subCloud(nh, subNameIr, 1),
```

(note using `subNameIr` when creating both the Image and Cloud subscribers).

It looks like this should be:

```
spinner(4), subNameCloud(basetopic + "/cloud"), subNameIr(basetopic + "/ir_image"), 
subImageIr(nh, subNameIr, 1), subCloud(nh, subNameCloud, 1),
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-01-14**:
Touche! Awesome. Thank you! I spent almost 9 hours trying to figure out where the error laid in the code. After getting repeatedly frustrated, I decided to post a question on this site. Now thanks to your careful eye, I can go to bed happy. Thanks again!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-15**:
If you feel @ahendrix has answered your question, could you please mark it as answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of it?

Thanks.

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-01-15**:
Done. Thanks!